# Setting up multi-user virtual environment with Jupyter

Tags: python, openstack, jupyter

I want to set up a virtual environment to allow my teammates to share resources and collaborate more effectively. As such I am setting an OpenStack instance with R, Python, etc. installed such that anyone can connect to a pre-configured environment with all the necessary software for them to get started. I want everyone to be able to connect to the VM, have access to all the files in the remote machine, and I want to allow them to use Jupyter as an interface to explore/write/execute.

Is it good practice for multiple users to be accessing the same Jupyter server? It seems like two people editing the same notebook could lead to problematic behavior. Also since my VM is running on a public IP, I would probably need some authentication - is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following suggestions for you:

1. Setup `sshd` server on your VM, which I think most of the time just works out of box unless it's a Windows VM...
2. Assign each user a username and password and a group called 'jptr_users', if they care at all their own resources being exposed to others. If they don't, then having a non-root non-admin global account for the users is fine.
3. Allow users to forward port with `-X` (X-term) option, so that they can pull the notebook session up in their local browsers.
4. `nice` the notebook server process, just so that kernel doesn't crash when you have too many users running things at the same time. Also advise users to `nice` everything they run on the VM. After all, it's a shared machine.
5. Avoiding overwriting the same notebook by different sessions of edits can be complicated. Have a git repo setup in the directory. Then each user will create a duplicate of a target notebook for editing. Once they are done with the duplicate, have them `git status` to check if the original is edited. If yes, they have to merge by hand. If not, overwrite the target with duplicate and commit. These steps are not atomic, so there are still things that can go wrong...
6. If your team is small, you can try to have them ping on a chat when they start  and finish editing on a file. One nice chatting app for development is https://www.flowdock.com/.

Hope this helps. Best of luck!